# How to Display Navigation Drawer in every activities?

Tags: java, android

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();

    }
```

mobile_form

```
public class mobile_form extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        view= findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

}

i need to add in second activity

Comment: Why don't you use Fragment ?

Comment: @AjayShrestha  i dosent know to do it can u help me

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one activity and inside multiple fragments